# Is it possible to get the difference from two dynamic arrays regardless of their order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

If I have two arrays and I try to find their difference..

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7] - [2, 1]
```

I get :

```
[3, 6, 7]
```

But if I flip those arrays around

```
[2, 1] - [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7]
```

I get :

```
[]
```

My question is, being that my two arrays are dynamic, I need to know if there is a difference in between both arrays regardless of their order. What's the simplest expression to find that?

Comment: My answer for now is just using a ternary to count which is bigger, and subtracting the larger one..

Comment: Comparing lengths of two arrays to determine which goes where seems pretty simple to me

Comment: What should the result be if the arrays are `[1,2,3]` & `[3,4,5]` (since this case isn’t illustrated in your example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define it:

```
class Array
  def diff(o)
    (o - self) + (self - o)    # alternatively: (o + self) - (o & self)
  end
end

[2, 1].diff [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7] # [3, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7].diff [2, 1] # [3, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 3, 1].diff [2, 4, 5]    # [4, 5, 3, 3, 1]
[2, 4, 5].diff [2, 3, 3, 1]    # [3, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

The correct answer probably depends on what you want in the end, though, as the second two examples above show.

If you only want unique values, you'll want to convert the two inputs to sets first, and return the result as an array:

```
class Array
  def diff(o)
    (o.to_set ^ to_set).to_a   # or simply (o.to_set ^ self).to_a
  end
end

[2, 4, 5].diff [2, 3, 3, 1]    # [4, 5, 3, 1]
```

(There might be a built-in Rails method, too.)

Comment: Thanks Denis. This is really well thought out. And MxyL's was too. Both of you, thanks!

Comment: `self.to_set` can be replaced with `self` because `Set#^` accepts an enumerable object.

Comment: +1, as this `(o - self) + (self - o)` is much expressive at-least for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Set#^`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-5E):

```
require 'set'

([2, 1].to_set ^ [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7]).to_a
# => [3, 6, 7]
([1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7].to_set ^ [2, 1]).to_a
# => [3, 6, 7]
```

According to the documentation:

> `Set#^` returns a new set containing elements exclusive between the set and
>   the given enumerable object.

Comment: Needs `require 'set'` outside of Rails: `Set.new([1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7]) - Set.new([2,1])` :-)